# Change Key names in PHP Arrays if Date in Key is Matched in date range of other array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I know this question been asked before changing of keys in array, 
but what i want if date in the key is matched with the date range then that key should be replaced.

e-g
I have an array with the keys of whole month from date 1 to date 31

```
[Project 456] => Array
    (
        [2014-12-01] => 5
        [2014-12-02] => 00
        [2014-12-03] => 00
        [2014-12-04] => 00
        [2014-12-05] => 00
        [2014-12-06] => 00
        [2014-12-07] => 00
        [2014-12-08] => 00
        [2014-12-09] => 00
        [2014-12-10] => 8
        [2014-12-11] => 00
        [2014-12-12] => 00
        [2014-12-13] => 00
        [2014-12-14] => 00
        [2014-12-15] => 00
        [2014-12-16] => 00
        [2014-12-17] => 00
        [2014-12-18] => 00
        [2014-12-19] => 00
        [2014-12-20] => 00
        [2014-12-21] => 00
        [2014-12-22] => 00
        [2014-12-23] => 00
        [2014-12-24] => 00
        [2014-12-25] => 00
        [2014-12-26] => 00
        [2014-12-27] => 00
        [2014-12-28] => 00
        [2014-12-29] => 00
        [2014-12-30] => 00
        [2014-12-31] => 00
        [Total] => 13
    )
```

and i want if dates matched with date range of other array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AvailableLeaveTypes] => Sick
            [TotalAllocatedLeaves] => 6
            [TotalLeavesTaken] => 3
            [Balance] => 3
            [LeaveFrom] => 2014-12-05
            [LeaveTo] => 2014-12-08
        )
)
```

Then Keys of first array with matching dates Should Replace with LeaveType which is `Sick`

which approach would i have to follow??

==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

**Update:**

The First Array is Actually the MultiDimentional Array.

Here is full Array

```
Array
(
    [Date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01
            [1] => 02
            [2] => 03
            [3] => 04
            [4] => 05
            [5] => 06
            [6] => 07
            [7] => 08
            [8] => 09
            [9] => 10
            [10] => 11
            [11] => 12
            [12] => 13
            [13] => 14
            [14] => 15
            [15] => 16
            [16] => 17
            [17] => 18
            [18] => 19
            [19] => 20
            [20] => 21
            [21] => 22
            [22] => 23
            [23] => 24
            [24] => 25
            [25] => 26
            [26] => 27
            [27] => 28
            [28] => 29
            [29] => 30
            [30] => 31
            [Total] => Total Hours Worked
        )

    [Day] => Array
        (
            [0] => Monday
            [1] => Tuesday
            [2] => Wednesday
            [3] => Thursday
            [4] => Friday
            [5] => Saturday
            [6] => Sunday
            [7] => Monday
            [8] => Tuesday
            [9] => Wednesday
            [10] => Thursday
            [11] => Friday
            [12] => Saturday
            [13] => Sunday
            [14] => Monday
            [15] => Tuesday
            [16] => Wednesday
            [17] => Thursday
            [18] => Friday
            [19] => Saturday
            [20] => Sunday
            [21] => Monday
            [22] => Tuesday
            [23] => Wednesday
            [24] => Thursday
            [25] => Friday
            [26] => Saturday
            [27] => Sunday
            [28] => Monday
            [29] => Tuesday
            [30] => Wednesday
        )

    [Project 456] => Array
        (
            [2014-12-01] => 5
            [2014-12-02] => 00
            [2014-12-03] => 00
            [2014-12-04] => 00
            [2014-12-05] => 00
            [2014-12-06] => 00
            [2014-12-07] => 00
            [2014-12-08] => 00
            [2014-12-09] => 00
            [2014-12-10] => 8
            [2014-12-11] => 00
            [2014-12-12] => 00
            [2014-12-13] => 00
            [2014-12-14] => 00
            [2014-12-15] => 00
            [2014-12-16] => 00
            [2014-12-17] => 00
            [2014-12-18] => 00
            [2014-12-19] => 00
            [2014-12-20] => 00
            [2014-12-21] => 00
            [2014-12-22] => 00
            [2014-12-23] => 00
            [2014-12-24] => 00
            [2014-12-25] => 00
            [2014-12-26] => 00
            [2014-12-27] => 00
            [2014-12-28] => 00
            [2014-12-29] => 00
            [2014-12-30] => 00
            [2014-12-31] => 00
            [Total] => 13
        )
)
```

I thought if i could use IF statement that if Top Arrays Keys are not Day and Date then inside dates can be matched. So the Probably outcome of comparing two arrays would be.

```
Array
(
    [Date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01
            [1] => 02
            [2] => 03
            [3] => 04
            [4] => 05
            [5] => 06
            [6] => 07
            [7] => 08
            [8] => 09
            [9] => 10
            [10] => 11
            [11] => 12
            [12] => 13
            [13] => 14
            [14] => 15
            [15] => 16
            [16] => 17
            [17] => 18
            [18] => 19
            [19] => 20
            [20] => 21
            [21] => 22
            [22] => 23
            [23] => 24
            [24] => 25
            [25] => 26
            [26] => 27
            [27] => 28
            [28] => 29
            [29] => 30
            [30] => 31
            [Total] => Total Hours Worked
        )

    [Day] => Array
        (
            [0] => Monday
            [1] => Tuesday
            [2] => Wednesday
            [3] => Thursday
            [4] => Friday
            [5] => Saturday
            [6] => Sunday
            [7] => Monday
            [8] => Tuesday
            [9] => Wednesday
            [10] => Thursday
            [11] => Friday
            [12] => Saturday
            [13] => Sunday
            [14] => Monday
            [15] => Tuesday
            [16] => Wednesday
            [17] => Thursday
            [18] => Friday
            [19] => Saturday
            [20] => Sunday
            [21] => Monday
            [22] => Tuesday
            [23] => Wednesday
            [24] => Thursday
            [25] => Friday
            [26] => Saturday
            [27] => Sunday
            [28] => Monday
            [29] => Tuesday
            [30] => Wednesday
        )

    [Project 456] => Array
        (
            [2014-12-01] => 5
            [2014-12-02] => 00
            [2014-12-03] => 00
            [2014-12-04] => 00
            [2014-12-05-Sick] => 00
            [2014-12-06-Sick] => 00
            [2014-12-07-Sick] => 00
            [2014-12-08-Sick] => 00
            [2014-12-09] => 00
            [2014-12-10] => 8
            [2014-12-11] => 00
            [2014-12-12] => 00
            [2014-12-13] => 00
            [2014-12-14] => 00
            [2014-12-15] => 00
            [2014-12-16] => 00
            [2014-12-17] => 00
            [2014-12-18] => 00
            [2014-12-19] => 00
            [2014-12-20] => 00
            [2014-12-21] => 00
            [2014-12-22] => 00
            [2014-12-23] => 00
            [2014-12-24] => 00
            [2014-12-25] => 00
            [2014-12-26] => 00
            [2014-12-27] => 00
            [2014-12-28] => 00
            [2014-12-29] => 00
            [2014-12-30] => 00
            [2014-12-31] => 00
            [Total] => 13
        )
)
```

But i do not want to disturb the order it is in. only want to change the keys.

Here is the other Complete Array but only 1 of them has the data for date range.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AvailableLeaveTypes] => Sick
            [TotalAllocatedLeaves] => 6
            [TotalLeavesTaken] => 3
            [Balance] => 3
            [LeaveFrom] => 2014-12-05
            [LeaveTo] => 2014-12-08
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AvailableLeaveTypes] => On Leave
            [TotalAllocatedLeaves] => 0
            [TotalLeavesTaken] => 0
            [Balance] => 0
            [LeaveFrom] => 
            [LeaveTo] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AvailableLeaveTypes] => Earned Leave
            [TotalAllocatedLeaves] => 0
            [TotalLeavesTaken] => 0
            [Balance] => 0
            [LeaveFrom] => 
            [LeaveTo] => 
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AvailableLeaveTypes] => Casual
            [TotalAllocatedLeaves] => 0
            [TotalLeavesTaken] => 0
            [Balance] => 0
            [LeaveFrom] => 
            [LeaveTo] => 
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AvailableLeaveTypes] => Annual
            [TotalAllocatedLeaves] => 0
            [TotalLeavesTaken] => 0
            [Balance] => 0
            [LeaveFrom] => 
            [LeaveTo] => 
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AvailableLeaveTypes] => Unpaid
            [TotalAllocatedLeaves] => 0
            [TotalLeavesTaken] => 0
            [Balance] => 0
            [LeaveFrom] => 
            [LeaveTo] => 
        )

)
```

So if `LeaveFrom` and `LeaveTo` is Null The First Array will not be updated for it. just only for those who has From/To Dates.

Comment: If keys `2014-12-05` and `2014-12-08` will be replaced by `Sick`, then they are no longer unique and will be overwritten by the last application.

Comment: @Ghost
ok. can sick be concatenated with date of the Key, i mean `[2014-12-31-Sick] => 00`, This way it can be unique?

Comment: yes, then you could do that, just unset the key that matched then assign newly created key, most likely you would need to sort it by key again.

Comment: @Ghost
But how to match dates in keys of 1st array with dates in range of other array?

Comment: you should convert all date values to timestamp using `strtotime()` and compare using comparison operators

Comment: @anp
i can compare dates if they are in variables but they are in arrays comparing dates in different arrays in different locations.. thats what i am trying to ask, plus the other array has a range not actual dates.

Comment: @SizzlingCode you should probably add some expected results. and by the way, how many dimensions does this both array have? does the date range array contain a lot more sub objects inside? and the project array as well?

Comment: @SizzlingCode anyway my suggestion is, just keep those keys intact they create another dimension for all the pertinent info in another array inside it.

Comment: @Ghost
Sir, i added both arrays comlete and the result i want.
Actually i want to Get the LeaveType if the Employee is on leave inside that project.

Comment: @SizzlingCode here is an example on how to detect if date is in range https://eval.in/235719, i donot suggest changing array keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a simple foreach loop. First off, clean the leave array with objects with those empty leave from an leave to since you wouldn't need them to be processed:

```
$leaves_array = array_filter($leaves_array, function($val){
    return (!empty($val->LeaveFrom) && !empty($val->LeaveTo));
});
```

Then on the loops, the parent loop is the leaves, the inner loop is the project.

Try to convert them into a DateTime object so that you could compare date easily. Then in the processing, if that key is inside the date range leave, put it inside a temporary holder, then unset it. After the unsetting, push another set of those new keys then resort it by key:

```
foreach($leaves_array as $leave) {
    $range = array();
    foreach ($project_array['Project 456'] as $date => $value) {
        try {
            $new_date = new DateTime($date);
            $from = new DateTime($leave->LeaveFrom);
            $to = new DateTime($leave->LeaveTo);
            if($new_date >= $from && $new_date <= $to) {
                $range[] = $date . '-Sick';
                unset($project_array['Project 456'][$date]);
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {

        }

    }
    // changes
    foreach($range as $range_date) {
        $project_array['Project 456'][$range_date] = '00';
    }
    // resort
    ksort($project_array['Project 456']);
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DyHSxb)

But my suggestion is, instead of changing those keys, why not create an array inside those dates, then just push pertinent details inside it, like leave dates and stuff.

Comment: Many Thanks. It Worked like a charm, i thou edited somethings for my needs but overall you saved the day :)